# How can I implement i18n and l10n in Qwik?

Tags: localization, internationalization, qwik

I want to create a new website using Qwik from builder.io.

I can't see in their docs how I can support multi languages.

I want my website to be English by default (no locale to be set in URLs) and for extra languages I want to include the locale in the URL.

For example:

```
https://example.com/blog => for English
https://example.com/fr/blog => For French
https://example.com/ru/blog => For Russian
```

How can I do that?

Comment: This package is useful for i18n integration with qwik   https://github.com/robisim74/qwik-speak

Answer (score 1):

You can find everything related to internationalization with Qwik here:

https://qwik.builder.io/docs/integrations/i18n/#internationalization

There are currently no official package for that. However two packages from the community stand out:

- $localize: https://github.com/mhevery/qwik-i18n
- qwik-speak: https://github.com/robisim74/qwik-speak

Feel free to join the Qwik community on discord.

Also for that kind of "simple" question you can try the ChatGPT native integration within qwik doc site search bar.

Answer (score 0):

This package provide i18n integration with qwikjs https://github.com/robisim74/qwik-speak